# Remove all the Html elements with a particular Class in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a container. A div element.It has a lot of nested elements in it. I want to delete all the Html elements with a particular class .Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is not enough information to look at the problem...

Comment: share your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `descendant selector`,

```
$('#container .nestedElement').remove();
```

Or you can use `.find()`

```
$('#container').find('.nestedElement').remove();
```

---

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="nestedElement">first</div>
  <div class="nestedElement">one</div>
  <div class="b">some</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is nothing to suggest that `container` is the id

Comment: @ArunPJohny I just presumed that. :|

Comment: @ArunKumar If you feel anyone of the answers provided here satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with that answer in order to show your acceptance to the future visitors.. And it is not a compulsion... :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

We can target any element for removal:

```
$( ".hello" ).remove();
```

This will result in a DOM structure with the  element deleted:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It remove `hello` class outside `container` also.

Answer (score 1):

Markup assumed

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">first</div>
  <div class="a">one</div>
  <div class="b">some</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$(".container .a").remove();
```

or

```
$(".container").find(".a").remove();
```

or

```
$(".container div[class='a']").remove();
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/6os0anpf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple JQuery action

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n173napo/

Sample List:

```
<div id="list">
   <a class="class1">Class 1</a>
   <a class="class1">Class 1</a>
   <a class="class2">Class 2</a>
   <a class="class1">Class 1</a>
   <a class="class1">Class 1</a>
   <a class="class2">Class 2</a>
   <a class="class1">Class 1</a>
   <a class="class1">Class 1</a>
</div>
```

Remove all with class2 inside list in list using CSS selector

```
$('#list .class2').remove();
```

The selector selects all elements with class "class2" into the unique element with id "list"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divelement .perticularClass").remove();
```

Where `#divelement` is your div element id and `perticularClass` is class selector for elements to  remove from div element.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is not a good thing to get into.
Better in pure javascript

```
for (x = 0; x <= document.getElementsByClassName("YOURCLASSNAME").lenght -1; x++){
    document.getElementsByClassName("YOURCLASSNAME")[x].parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName("YOURCLASSNAME")[x]);
}
```